# Handling null loops in php

Tags: php, loops, if-statement

Python offers a for...else structure [but not] like this:

```
for value in i:
    print value
else:
    print 'i is empty'
```

What's the nearest equivalent to this in PHP?

Edit: see @Evpok's comment below - the for...else doesn't actually work as the print statements suggest it does. My mistake - sorry!

Comment: According to http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement, the `else` clause is called at the end of the loop, unless a `break` statement is reached, not only when `i` is empty.

Comment: @Evpok you're right - my mistake. Now I'd like to know the pythonic way to write the PHP code in the answers below!

Comment: I can think of nothing but `if not i: ... else: for...`

Comment: you have not accepted any of the answers.  do you want something that satisfies the print statement, or something that works like python?

Answer (score 8):

```
if (!empty($array)){
   foreach ($array as $val)
        echo $val;
}
else
    echo "array is empty";
```

Answer (score 8):

To account for all traversables, including uncountable ones, the correct approach would be:

```
$iterated = false;
foreach ($traversable as $value) {
    $iterated = true;

    echo $value;
}

if (!$iterated) {
    echo 'traversable is empty';
}
```

If you are writing generalized code this is the way to go. If you know that you will get a countable traversable, the `count` method is obviously nicer to read.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (count($i) > 0) {
   foreach ($i as $x) { ... }
} else {
   echo 'i is empty';
}
```

assuming `i` is an array.

Answer (score 3):

Doing exact implementation as the python manual says is this:

```
$count = count($my_array);
$cntr = 0;
foreach($my_array as $my_value)
{
  $cntr++;
  // do the loop work
}
if($cntr == $count)
{
   // all elements treated, do the 'python-else' part.
}
```

Comment: @totten The philosophy here is that it is better to be explicit about what you are doing. Since it becomes much clearer for people who will read your code.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this does not answer your specific example, but I have used [goto](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) as a workaround for another for -> else Python to PHP problem:

```
foreach(range(2,100) as $n){
    for($x = 2; $x < $n; $x++){
        if($n % $x==0){
            print $n . ' equals ' . $x . ' * ' . $n/$x . '<br>';
            goto end;   
        }
    }
        echo $n . ' is a prime number.<br>';    
        end:
    }
```

Perhaps this is a more practical answer.

Comment: Wouldn't a break have accomplished the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there is no such thing as `forelse loop` in PHP, but if you are using `laravel`, in their `blade templating engine` they have a `forelse loop` that goes something like this

```
@forelse($arrays as $string)
  <p>{{ $string }}</p>
@empty
  <p>Empty</p>
@endforelse
```

Further information here -> https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#loops

but you can make a work around if you are not using `laravel's blade templating engine`, something like this would be a great approach

```
if(count($arrays)) {
  foreach($arrays as $string) {
    echo '<p>'. $string .'</p>';
  }
} else {
  echo '<p>Empty!</p>';
}
```

if you came up with a better idea, beep me please.